# WPF Grid content not showing up inside Expander

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My Grid content is invisible when the Grid is put inside an Expander. It is there in the Designer, it lines out the objects as you can see in the image, but it does not show up when the application is launched.
What did I do wrong?

Designer screenshot:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNphw.png)

XAML Code:

```
<Expander Background="#FFEEEEEE" Opacity="0.95" MouseUp="ResetCursor" x:Name="CatalogusExpander" Header="Catalogus" Width="125" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsExpanded="True" Height="25" ExpandDirection="Up">
    <Grid Height="250" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
            labore et dolore magna aliqua
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Expander>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the `Height` Property of the `Expander` to `25` and therefore it can not show the `Grid` because its greater than the given space.

Try this `XAML` (it takes care of the `Header` size and expands correctly)

```
<Expander Background="#FFEEEEEE" Opacity="0.95" MouseUp="ResetCursor" x:Name="CatalogusExpander" Width="125" Header="Catalogus" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsExpanded="True" ExpandDirection="Up" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <Grid Height="250" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,-175,0" Background="#FFEEEEEE" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
        labore et dolore magna aliqua
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Expander>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! I understand what I did wrong. But my method was working when <Grid> was replaced by a <Canvas> (what it actually was before I deciedd to redesign the expander), so I expected it to work with Grid too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the Grid inside the Expander Content:

```
<Expander Background="#FFEEEEEE" Opacity="0.95" MouseUp="ResetCursor" x:Name="CatalogusExpander" Header="Catalogus" Width="125" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsExpanded="True" Height="25" ExpandDirection="Up">
    <Expander.Content>
        <Grid Height="250" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                labore et dolore magna aliqua
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Expander.Content>
</Expander>
```

Comment: Thx for your quick answer. Unfortunately this has no effect, neither within a newly created WPF project: [see here](http://prntscr.com/lxvkjt)

Comment: That's weird, last time I had to do something like this it worked for me. It was a long time ago though, so maybe something changed that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

You have limited the Height of the expander to "25", so even when it expands, it can't go higher than 25. Consider either increasing the Height or removing the Height attribute

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it made me understand what I did wrong. This knowledge combined with the suggestion of @LittleBit led to the solution.